# css div styling is only applying to first line inside the div instead of everything inside div

Tags: html, css, indentation

I am trying to get several links to indent 200px.  I have enclosed them in div tags and styled the div tags in css within the same file.  I don't understand why only the first link indents and the others do not even though the are enclosed inside the div.  Can anyone spot what is happening here?

Here is my css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
   <html lang=en>  
     <head>
        <title>Amendment</title>

       <style>

        body {
            font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", New York, serif;
            background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
            background-position: center; 
            margin: 2.54cm;
            border: double;
            padding: 6mm;
        } 
        h1{
          font-size: 2.5em;
        }
        h2 {
          font-style: bold;
          font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        span.brown {
          background-color: brown;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 12pt;

        }
        b{
          color: green;
          background-color: white;
        }
        #fifthamendment{
          text-decoration: line-through;

        }
        li{
          list-style: none;
        }
        p:hover {
          background-color: white;
        }

        div {
           text-indent: 200px;
        }

        a:link.top {
            text-decoration: none;
             font-size: .90em;
        }
        a:link.linkout {
          text-decoration:underline;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
  <body>
```

And here is my html code:

```
<h1>Amendment Table of Contents</center></h1>

    <hr>

            <div>

                <a href="#Amendment1">Amendment 1: Freedom of Speech, Religion, Press</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment2">Amendment 2: Right to Bear Arms</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment3">Amendment 3: Quartering of Soldiers</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment4">Amendment 4: Searches and Seizures</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment5">Amendment 5: Due Process</a><br/>
   </div>
```

And this is how it appears in my browser:

```
Amendment Table of Contents

                             Amendment 1: Freedom of Speech, Religion, Press
Amendment 2: Right to Bear Arms
Amendment 3: Quartering of Soldiers
Amendment 4: Searches and Seizures
Amendment 5: Due Process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's what text-indent does.

Try one of these instead:

```
div {
   margin-left: 200px;
}

div{
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: What you want is Second option - padding. Everyting inside that div will have 200px space.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
            <a href="#Amendment1">Amendment 1: Freedom of Speech, Religion, Press</a><br/>
            <a href="#Amendment2">Amendment 2: Right to Bear Arms</a><br/>
            <a href="#Amendment3">Amendment 3: Quartering of Soldiers</a><br/>
            <a href="#Amendment4">Amendment 4: Searches and Seizures</a><br/>
            <a href="#Amendment5">Amendment 5: Due Process</a><br/>
 </div>
```

You have an extra `</div>` after the first `<a>` tag.

====update====

Only the first line is indented because `<a>` is an inline element. So all the `<a>` elements are considered as one paragraph. Using `padding` will act a little differently from `text-indent`: `padding` will move every element, while `text-indent` will move the first line of a text paragraph.

So if you need the literal indent effect, change `<a>` to `<p>`, or add "`display:block`" in CSS for these `<a>` elements.

Comment: Sorry, I had been playing with my code and forgot to delete that extra </div> tag before posting my question, but it was still happening even without that extra <div> being there. Using padding-left, as answered below, solved the issue.

Comment: If you want real "text-indent" - indent the first line of a text paragraph, you can change <a> (inline element) to <p> (block element) which is also more semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your HTML:

```
   <h1>Amendment Table of Contents</center></h1>

    <hr>

    <div>

                <a href="#Amendment1">Amendment 1: Freedom of Speech, Religion, Press</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment2">Amendment 2: Right to Bear Arms</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment3">Amendment 3: Quartering of Soldiers</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment4">Amendment 4: Searches and Seizures</a><br/>
                <a href="#Amendment5">Amendment 5: Due Process</a><br/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for your link placed exact center

```css
body {
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", New York, serif;
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  margin: 2.54cm;
  border: double;
  padding: 6mm;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
span.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
p {
  font-size: 12pt;
}
b {
  color: green;
  background-color: white;
}
#fifthamendment {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
p:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a:link.top {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .90em;
}
a:link.linkout {
  text-decoration: underline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Amendment Table of Contents</center></h1>

<hr>

<div>

  <a href="#Amendment1">Amendment 1: Freedom of Speech, Religion, Press</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#Amendment2">Amendment 2: Right to Bear Arms</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#Amendment3">Amendment 3: Quartering of Soldiers</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#Amendment4">Amendment 4: Searches and Seizures</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#Amendment5">Amendment 5: Due Process</a>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to shift complete DIV to right by adding required margin-left to it. Like

```
div {
    margin-left: xxxPX;   \\ Like 150px
}
```

It will shift your whole DIV to its right(replace xxx with what indent you want)